# Cleaner way to iterate over tuples in elixir

Tags: elixir

I find myself writing a pattern something like this pretty often and I feel it is not ideal:

```
Enum.filter(my_list, fn e -> 
   case e do 
     {:ok, x} -> true
     {:error, y} -> false 
   end 
end)
|> Enum.map(fn e -> {:ok, something} = e; something end)
```

Where my_list is created by some function that returns {:ok, x} or {:error, y}

I do this when I want to ignore the errors.

Have any alternatives for me?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell what you are doing without a complete working code sample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `for` with the pattern `{:ok, term}` for this. `for` automatically ignores all values in the enumerable which doesn't match the pattern, which facilitates this elegant solution:

```
iex(1)> my_list = [{:ok, 1}, {:error, 2}, {:ok, 3}, {:ok, 4}, {:error, 5}]
[ok: 1, error: 2, ok: 3, ok: 4, error: 5]
iex(2)> for {:ok, term} <- my_list, do: term
[1, 3, 4]
```